# Access Special Character Key from STD array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, stdarray

I have this array where I have a special character in the key. How Do I access its value ?

Usually, I would access the value like `$result->id`. Where id would be my key and result the array.

Now here, I have the key to be :  `J24-RN058900126115` . So when I try to access `$result->J24-RN058900126115`

So how Do I access the value from that key ?

Comment: e.g. `$result->{'J24-RN058900126115'}`

Comment: So, this is about a stdObject. There's no such thing as a std array.